# How to record message except which contain only words?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make my bot record every messages, but now I am in a trouble. It can only record the messages which contain only words like text and url. That means if I send a photo or a GIF from the searcher in Discord not via url, it won't record anything. Here are my codes for private message and group message:

For Private Message

```js
if (!msg.guild) {
        let channel = await client.channels.fetch("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").catch(err => console.log(err));
        let str = `${msg.author.tag} sent a private message\nID ${msg.author.id}\n-----\n${msg.content}`
        channel.send(str).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return;
    }
```

For Group Message

```js
if (msg.guild && msg.author.id != "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" && msg.guild.id == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") {
        let mStr = '';
        mStr = mStr +
            `-------------\n` +
            `EVENT SEND\n` +
            `USER ${msg.member.user.username}\n` +
            `CHANNEL ${msg.channel.name}\n` +
            `-------------\n` +
            `CONTAIN ${msg.content}`;
        client.channels.cache.get("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").send(mStr).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get attachments (imgages/files) with `msg.attachments` 
Get embeds with `msg.embeds` 
Get components(buttons/select menus) with `msg.components`

All of them return an array. To get the a specific value use square brackets with the according index `[i]` starting from `0` as the first element

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you meant. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, when u get a message you can access the message content with `message.content` as you already do. That gives you the written text. When you want the attachments you use `message.attachments` which gives back files/pictures. Because they could be multiple files attached to the message you get an array filled with the links to the files like `[ link.to.first , link.to.second ...]`. Same for embeds but you get an Embed Object in the Array: `[ embedData1, embedData2]`. Even when there is only one element an array gets created.